# Rails + Slim - MissingTemplate (in production)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ubuntu, capistrano, bundler, slim-lang

I have a project on Rails 3.2. Also i used haml as my template engine but i decided to use slim instead of haml. So i rewrite some views using slim. But when i pushed this changes to server i got strange error in production.

The error appears ONLY on pages which use slim as a template engine. On my development machine pages open great. To setup server i used [Rayan Byte's screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps)

How can i fix that?

**Error**:

```
Started GET "/" for 128.69.76.116 at 2013-04-12 11:19:31 +0000

Started GET "/ru/articles" for 128.69.76.116 at 2013-04-12 11:19:31 +0000
Processing by ArticlesController#index as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>"ru"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 180ms

ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template articles/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:ru], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}. Searched in:
  * "/home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/releases/20130412101936/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/gmaps4rails-1.5.6/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.14.0/app/views"
  * "/home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.2/app/views"
):
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
  /home/deployer/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:436:in `_run__609582508__process_action__934117167__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:339:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.8) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__319658905__call__322020128__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.8) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.8) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:136:in `forward'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:245:in `fetch'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:185:in `lookup'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:66:in `call!'
  rack-cache (1.2) lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  railties (3.2.8) lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:552:in `process_client'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:628:in `worker_loop'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:500:in `spawn_missing_workers'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:511:in `maintain_worker_count'
  unicorn (4.5.0) lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:277:in `join'
  unicorn (4.5.0) bin/unicorn:121:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `load'
  /home/deployer/apps/Chirch_app/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>'
```

**Gemfile**:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.13'
gem 'pg', '0.15.1'                                                                                  
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'                                                                         
gem 'haml', '4.0.2'                                                                                 
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
gem 'devise', '2.2.3'                                                                               
gem 'simple_form', '2.1.0'                                                                          
gem 'bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails', "0.3.1.19"                                                         
gem 'kaminari', '0.14.0'                                                                            
gem "cancan", '1.6.9'                                                                               
gem "carrierwave", '0.8.0'                                                                          
gem "rmagick", '2.13.2'                                                                             
gem 'gmaps4rails', '1.5.6'                                                                          
gem 'unicorn', '4.6.2'                                                                              
gem 'capistrano', '2.14.2'                                                                          
gem 'less-rails', '2.3.2'                                                                           
gem 'slim', '1.3.8'
gem 'haml2slim'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.4'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.2'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', '2.2.6'                                                            
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.2.3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'annotate', '~> 2.5.0'
  gem 'better_errors'                                                                               
  gem 'binding_of_caller'                                                                           
  gem 'brakeman'                                                                                    
  gem 'meta_request'                                                                                
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.0'
  gem 'rb-fsevent'                                                                                  
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.2'                                                                        
  gem 'terminal-notifier-guard'                                                                     
  gem 'launchy'                                                                                     
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'                                                                           
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'                                                                 
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.9.1'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.32.1'                                                                
end
```

Comment: Did you bundle and restart your server after deploying?

Comment: @sevenseacat I use capistrano, it bundles gems automatically. Yes, i restarted server.

Comment: So you don't have problem in development, but production only?

Comment: @BillyChan Yes, production only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the problem. After a long time of researching (unicorn and ngingx restarts didn't help) i just rebooted the whole Operating System and after that `Slim` page appeared.

Comment: My initial reaction to this was that there was no reason that a unicorn restart shouldn't fix the problem, as it should reload the entire rails stack and boot rails cleanly.  But after trying nginx and unicorn restarts that didn't help, we restarted the server and, Bob's your uncle, the error was resolved.  Sometimes, magical things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error, the template handle is still haml

```
:formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :haml]}
```

My guess is you `index` page includes some partial written in haml, thus brings the confuse. The local development machine may have some cache in browser thus no problem there.

How about your turn all haml template into slim, **delete all haml templates**(use `git rm`), remove `haml` gem from Gemfile, and try again?

Comment: My index page includes some partials and here you are right. But (i double checked) all partials and all views for index page (article) use slim. But my other views use haml. And i can't just remove them because i have a lot of them and i'm not sure that it will work. I want to do a soft migration.

Comment: @ExiRe, how about the layout template? Slim or haml? Either may bring conflict.

Comment: @ExiRe, there is nothing to fear if the codes are version controlled. Just checkout to a new branch and refactoring. Actually you can handle them in batch automatically only three steps involved: haml2slim, remove haml, fix minor errors if exist.

Comment: I am not afraid that, i use git every day. I am just not sure that just rewriting everything to use slim and removing haml will gem solve the problem. Everything works in development and SUDDENLY doesn't work in production. I suppose that there is some bug or problem with gemfile, or config's problem.

Comment: @ExiRe, how do you think the conflict between application.html.slim(or .haml) with other templates, some haml, some slim?